# Javascript MaxLength with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict the users to enter max ten characters. I was able to do so, but when I select a text and try to replace it, I'm unable to do so. For Ex: If I highlight on the "mm" then I'm unable to replace it as the max length is 10. How can I do so while having the maxlength?
Here is my js function:

```
$('div').on('keydown', function(event) {
  $('span').text('Total chars:' + $(this).text().length);
  if($(this).text().length === 10 && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put this jsfiddle link also  ?

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mikepaul/yph0Lzun/

Comment: @Marc Blur is not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use highlighted text length as parameter

```js
$('div').on('keydown', function(event) {
  var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  $('span').text('Total chars:' + $(this).text().length);
  if($(this).text().length === 10-selection && event.keyCode != 8) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">mm/dd/yyyy</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked on Chrome but not working on IE 11. When I'm clicking on the cell, the field the becoming editable, then I'm unable to change the highlighted text. Do you have any idea why?